# Debugging in VSCODE: Watching vectors with length > 1000

Tags: c++, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, gdb

I am using vscode on Ubuntu and debugging with GDB using the C/C++ extension. I am trying to view the contents of an STL vector in the watch view but I can only see the first 1000 elements. I know this has been discussed [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/76798) but is there a workaround or temp fix for this?

Thanks